# Does the rank transform preserve signum of Spearman correlation between parameter estimates across samples?

Tags: regression, estimators, ranking, spearman-rho, ranks

Suppose we have real-valued random variables $X$, $Y$, with noise $\epsilon$ that is independent of $X$ and $Y$ and $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon] = 0$, and measurable function $f$.

I am thinking about comparing estimates of $\beta$ in

$$Y = f(X;\beta) + \epsilon$$

with estimates with $\beta$ in

$$\operatorname{rank}(Y) = f(\operatorname{rank}(X); \beta) + \epsilon$$

where $\operatorname{rank}$ is the [dense ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Dense_ranking_(%221223%22_ranking)) function applied to a given sample.

Assume that the same estimator of $\beta$ is used for both regression equations.

I'm thinking about the inequality

$$\rho \left[\hat \beta_{\operatorname{original}}, \hat \beta_{\operatorname{ranked}} \right] > 0$$

where $\rho [\cdot, \cdot ]$ is the Spearman rank correlation and the estimates $\beta_{\operatorname{original}}, \hat \beta_{\operatorname{ranked}}$ are paired by sample.

Does the inequality hold over finite samples?

---

Here is a toy example using simple linear regression. Suppose $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y = 3 X + 10 + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Below I used sample sizes of 10, and repeated for $10^4$ samples.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy.stats import rankdata
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

def rank(X):
    return rankdata(X, method='dense')

fits = []
rfits = []
m = 10

for k in range(10000):

    x = np.random.normal(size=m)
    y = 3 * x + 10 + np.random.normal(size=m)
    fits.append(np.polyfit(x, y, deg=1))

    rx = rank(x)
    ry = rank(y)
    rfits.append(np.polyfit(rx, ry, deg=1))

fits = np.array(fits)
rfits = np.array(rfits)

plt.scatter(fits[:,0], rfits[:,0], alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Slope Estimate')
plt.ylabel('Slope on Ranks Estimate')
plt.title(f'Slope\n{spearmanr(fits[:,0], rfits[:,0]).correlation}')
plt.show()

plt.scatter(fits[:,1], rfits[:,1], alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Intercept Estimate')
plt.ylabel('Intercept on Ranks Estimate')
plt.title(f'Intercept\n{spearmanr(fits[:,1], rfits[:,1]).correlation}')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

These plots give me the impression that there is Spearman correlation between the slope parameters but not the intercept parameters. This would seem to falsify my conjecture.

It makes me wonder what are sufficient conditions for a parameter to satisfy the conjecture. One guess is that such parameters can be identified from the regression model's computation graph.

```py
from graphviz import Digraph

d = Digraph()

d.edge('beta_1', 'beta_1 * X')
d.edge('X', 'beta_1 * X')
d.edge('beta_0', 'beta_1 * X + beta_0')
d.edge('beta_1 * X', 'beta_1 * X + beta_0')
d.view()
```

[image]

Or maybe just intercepts don't work? I'm not sure.

---

Let us suppose that our estimator is least squares via (vanilla) gradient descent, thus taking on the assumption that $f$ is smooth in its parameters.

Comment: Surely your conjecture depends on what procedures you use to form the estimates!

Comment: Re "using the same estimator:" let $f(X,\beta)=\beta$ and apply OLS, so that the $\hat\beta$ are the arithmetic means of the $Y_i.$ In the ranked case with $n$ variables this estimator is a constant (equal to $(n+1)/2$), whence the correlation is exactly zero.  Thus you cannot hope to have a strict equality. For additional insight and constructing counterexamples, let $f(X,\beta)=\beta X$ (a univariate OLS problem), let $Y$ be uniform on $[0,1],$ let $a\gg 1,$ and set $X=Y+a$ when $|Y|\le 1/4$ and otherwise let $X=-Y.$

Comment: Here's an `R` simulation of the foregoing: `n <- 8;
beta <- replicate(5000, {
  y <- runif(n);
  x <- ifelse(y < 1/4, y + 10, -y);
  c(cor(x, y), cor(x, y, method = "spearman"))
});
cor(t(beta))` The correlation between the two estimates is approximately $-1/4.$

Comment: @whuber Yes, I can see how a hidden indicator variable like the one you introduced can violate the conjecture. It makes me wonder what conditions would be sufficient to refine the conjecture into something that holds. But I won't change the question. Feel free to post your comments as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Requiring non-[endogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endogeneity_(econometrics)) might help remove many counter-examples, but perhaps not all.

Comment: Surely you can generalize from this counterexample!  The "hidden indicator" is not essential.  The point is that the Spearman and Pearson correlations are so different that it's quite possible for their sample correlations to be negative.  This comes about, as in the example, because of the possibility of outlying values with high leverage in the regression.